# How to get date on last/previous saturday in given timezone

Tags: java

I want to calculate date on last Saturday. For e.g. If I run program today, it should give me date as 11 Feb.

Would time zone make a difference on this calculation, different date on same day in different timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (which I advise you to use):

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));
DateTime saturday = now.withDayOfWeek(6);
if (saturday.isAfter(now)) {
    saturday = saturday .minusWeeks(1);
}
System.out.println(saturday);
```

Comment: 6 here is for Saturday? Does Joda library expose it as Enum/Constant like Calendar.SATURDAY. Also would this work on first week of any year as subtracting one week would take you to previous year.

Comment: yes, it will take you to the previous year. I wasn't sure if 6 is for Saturday, but it seems it is.

Answer (score 2):

as long as you refer to the same Saturday, it will be on the same date anywhere in the world.
the term "last saturday" might be ambiguous though:

if i'm in japan and its 1:00 (am) on saturday, then for me "last saturday" started just an hour ago.
for someone in england it's still friday and his "last Saturday" started (and ended) about a week ago.

in this case we might refer to "last Saturday" by different date but of course we in fact refer to different days.

Comment: But the "last" saturday can be different. Assume in one time zone it's already saturday while on the other it's still friday - in that case the last saturday will be a week apart (depending on your definition of last - otherwise it's saturday/sunday)

Comment: @Voo i was just writing that up while you posted the comment :)