# php - get most recently passed saturday (last saturday)

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the timestamp from last saturday (every week)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896452/getting-the-timestamp-from-last-saturday-every-week)

If today is Sunday, April 8th... i would want my date varaible set to Saturday, April 7th.

If today is Saturday, April 7th... i would want my date variable set to Saturday, March 31st.

The answer here: [How to get date on last/previous saturday in given timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285528/how-to-get-date-on-last-previous-saturday-in-given-timezone)  would work, except if today was Sunday, April 8th, it would give me Saturday, March 31st... which is not what i want.

Comment: would `strtotime('last saturday;);` work?

Comment: Do you want to find a UNIX timestamp or a formatted date/time string?

Comment: @hakre woops.  I should have assumed a question like this had an answer that easy to find.  ):

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
strtotime("last Saturday")
```

not sure if you need it in a date format as that will give you a timestamp.  if you need a date I can edit.

edit:

```
date('Ymd', strtotime("last Saturday"));
```

Comment: John can you format it to yyyyMMdd please?  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). For example, what you probably want is:

```php
$ts = strtotime('last saturday');
```

If you want a formatted date/time string, you can do:

```php
$dateStr = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last saturday'));
```