# Get data to display using strtotime

Tags: php

I use `strtotime()` to display a given data, for example every Saturday. The problem is that when Sunday comes the data is not display. What i want is to be able to let the data stay from Saturday to Wednesday for example.

```
DATE = "'".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("saturday"))."'";
```

Comment: Let me understand what you mean... Are you showing this on a website for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this would be to:

1. Check if today's date is saturday.
2. If it IS saturday, then do: `DATE = "'".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("saturday"))."'";`
3. If it's NOT saturday, then do: `DATE = "'".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Saturday"))."'";`

I got this trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096978/php-get-most-recently-passed-saturday-last-saturday)!
Hope this helps!

If that's not good enough, maybe you could store this data to a database or a local file but that's overkill!

Comment: THANKS HOW COULD I NT THINK OF THAT!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display last saturday only on specific days, try using this code:

```
if(in_array(date('w'), array(3,4,5,6)) {
     echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Saturday"));
}
```